# ASP .NET Core Identity in Winforms login not authenticating

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, authentication, asp.net-identity

I am using C# in a Winforms app and I have Identity wired up to where I can find users in the database.  I have a simple login form that I cannot get working.  I can find the user but I cannot verify the user via the password.  I have a textbox Username, and one for Password, a button, and a Label for displaying the result.  Here is my code:

```
private async void LoginButton_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username.Text) && 
        !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password.Text))
    {
        var context = new MyDbContext();
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new 
            UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

        //THIS SUCCESSFULLY FINDS THE USER
        ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(UxUsername.Text);

        if (user == null)
        {
            ResultLabel.Text = "NOT FOUND";
        }

        if (userManager.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user.PasswordHash, Password.Text)
            != PasswordVerificationResult.Failed)
        {
            ResultLabel.Text = "MATCH FOR USER AND PASSWORD!";
        }

        ResultLabel.Text = "NOT FOUND";
    }
}
```

I have also tried this and I could not even get the user back - it was null:

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(Username.Text, Password.Text);
```

I am using this same database for an MVC app and I am logging in just fine with the same exact credentials.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` from `SignInManager` class to authenticate your user.

```
ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(UxUsername.Text);
var signInResult = _signInManager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, ,User.Password, false);
```

To use `SignInManager` you should inject it to your form class.

> Note: **SignInManager** is in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`

Comment: How do I bring in SignInManager to my Winforms app?  I did look into that, but I couldn't get it to work in my project.

Comment: I was able to bring in SignInManager, but it I brought it in from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin - that allowed me to use _signInManager.PasswordSignIn, but that still gave me a SignInStatus failure.